# Excel RibbonX read an Editbox value

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I am trying to store a value in an EditBox and then use it for other subroutines. I can't find the appropriate VBA code to do that, appreciate any help. thank you.

my Editbox xml code: `<editBox id="UserN" label="User name" enabled="false" getText="UserN_getText"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a backed property for the control's content, so you could access the value at any point of time in the add-in or VBA programmatically. To get the value and set up the cached values you could use `getText` and `onChange` callbacks with the following signatures:

- The `onChange` callback is called when the value in the edit box is changed and committed by the user.

```
C#: void OnChange(IRibbonControl control, string text)
VBA: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
C++: HRESULT OnChange([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in] BSTR *pbstrText)
Visual Basic: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
```

- The `getText` callback gets the text to display in the edit box.

```
C#: string GetText(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub GetText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
C++: HRESULT GetText([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] BSTR *pbstrText)
Visual Basic: Function GetText(control As IRibbonControl) As String
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. my response above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Eugene.
I managed to get this part right, the part that I am struggling with is reading the value of the editbox: when the file is first open, my excel connects to an Access database and get a value then write it in the editbox (the user can't change it). In my different other subroutines, I wan't to be able to use that same value without reconnecting to the database.
I know the code below won't work, but just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
Sub ReturnValue()

Set X = IRibbonControl
For Each X In IRibbonControl
    If X.ID = "UserN" Then
        MsgBox X.Label
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next X
End Sub
```